# Reading and Writing Messages from a Socket

Tags: java, android, socket, tcp

This is code from my android client which communicates over wifi to a small server program *(not coded in java)*. This is my first time playing around with sockets, so I'm sure there are lots of little gotchas to worry about. For this project I am limited to Java 7.

The protocol for sending a message is

- 4 Bytes for an integer message size M
- M Bytes for the message payload

The 4 Byte size is trimmed from the payload when reviving and added to the payload when sending.

I decided that the user might want to be able to add and drop connections, so I made a class to handle the socket, input stream and output stream. I didn't create every function of the three classes, I just picked a functions I needed.

```
public final class SocketIO {

    private Socket socket;

    private InputStream input;

    private OutputStream output;

    public SocketIO(){
        socket = null;
        input = null;
        output = null;
    }

    public void connect(final String ip, final int port) throws IOException {
        close();
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        input = socket.getInputStream();
        output = socket.getOutputStream();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        if (socket == null){
            return false;
        }
        else if (socket.isConnected()){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            socket = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    }

    public void read(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            throw new IOException("Socket not connected");
        }
        input.read(bytes);

    }

    public int read(byte[] bytes, int i, int remaining) throws IOException {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            throw new IOException("Socket not connected");
        }
        return input.read(bytes, i, remaining);
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            throw new IOException("Socket not connected");
        }
        output.write(bytes);
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (!isConnected()) {
            throw new IOException("Socket not connected");
        }
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

I created two `Runnable` classes to read and write to the `SocketIO` class. They each require a `Queue<byte[]>` to accept incoming or send outgoing message payloads. For this I have been using a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.

```
public final class ByteWriter implements Runnable {

    private final Queue<byte[]> queue;

    final private SocketIO io;

    public ByteWriter(final SocketIO serverIo, final Queue<byte[]> source) {
        io = serverIo;
        queue = source;
    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (io.isConnected()){
                    while (queue.size() > 0) {
                        final byte[] sendBytes = queue.remove();
                        io.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sendBytes.length).array());
                        io.write(sendBytes);
                        io.flush();
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Reader:

```
public final class ByteReader implements Runnable {

    private final Queue<byte[]> queue;

    final private SocketIO io;

    public ByteReader(final SocketIO serverIo, final Queue<byte[]> destination) {
        io = serverIo;
        queue = destination;
    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (!io.isConnected()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    continue;
                }
                final byte[] receiveSizeBytes = new byte[4];
                io.read(receiveSizeBytes);
                final int receiveSize = ByteBuffer.wrap(receiveSizeBytes).getInt();

                final byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[receiveSize];

                int bytesRemaining = receiveSize;
                int offset = 0;
                while (bytesRemaining > 0) {
                    final int readCount = io.read(receiveBytes, offset, bytesRemaining);
                    offset += readCount;
                    bytesRemaining -= readCount;
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                queue.add(receiveBytes);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The class which manages these new objects:

```
public final class ServerConnection implements Runnable {

    private final String ip;

    private final int port;

    private final SocketIO io;

    private final Thread writer;

    private final Thread reader;

    public ServerConnection(
            final String ipAddress,
            final int portNumber,
            final Queue<byte[]> incoming,
            final Queue<byte[]> outgoing) {
        ip = ipAddress;
        port = portNumber;

        io = new SocketIO();
        writer = new Thread(new ByteWriter(io, outgoing));
        reader = new Thread(new ByteReader(io, incoming));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        writer.start();
        reader.start();

        try {
            io.connect(ip, port);
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                if (!io.isConnected()) {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            io.close();
            writer.interrupt();
            reader.interrupt();
            writer.join();
            reader.join();
        } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of establishing the connection in my program:

> ```
> public class ControlPanel extends Activity {
>
>     private final Queue<byte[]> incoming = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
>
>     private final Queue<byte[]> outgoing = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
>
>     private Thread connection = new Thread();
>
> .......
>
>     public void connectServer(final View view){
>         connection.interrupt();
>         try {
>             connection.join();
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
>         connection = new Thread(new ServerConnection(editText.getText().toString(), 1337, incoming, outgoing));
>         connection.start();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resource leaks

You `isConnected` method has the potential to leak open resources. If the method is called while isConnected() on the underlying socket returns `false`, the socket will be set to `null` without calling `close()` on the socket.

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    if (socket == null){
        return false;
    }
    else if (socket.isConnected()){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        socket = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Remember that the [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) explicitly states that the method must be idempotent, so closing a socket 2 times shouldn't give you a error.

### Inconsistent order of modifers

> ```
> private final Queue<byte[]> queue;
> final private SocketIO io;
> ```

Choosing a consistent order of modifers makes your code looks better, I would go for `private final`, as this is used everywhere in your project

```
private final Queue<byte[]> queue;
private final SocketIO io;
```

### Swallowing `InterruptedException`

> ```
>    try {
>        connection.join();
>    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>        e.printStackTrace();
>    }
> ```

Swallowing/suppressing this exception isn't good practise, as it blocks the propagation of the interrupted state. If you are forced to catch it, you should either make a looping structure that set the threads interrupted state at the end, or set the threads intterupted state directly by calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

```
    try {
        connection.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

### Unused thread

> ```
> private Thread connection = new Thread();
> ```

By defining a `Thread` that is never started, you have the potential to create a [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9921561/1542723).

You should use either use a null object, or a wrapper object that you crafted using the null-object design pattern.

```
private Thread connection = null;
```

A other way to this, is to start the thread directly. This is considered more as a hack than a proper solution.

```
private Thread connection = new Thread();
{
     connection.start();
}
```

### Sleeping Threads

You use a large number of call to `Thread.sleep()` in your code, this is more like a anti-pattern for proper usage of locking. In the ideal world, you should let the threads wait for each other using `Object.wait()` in combination with `Object.notifyAll()`. Incase of your socket, don't sleep, but call the `read()` method again. Using this mechanism you can signal multiple conditions, like a new thing to read, but also if there is nothing left to write.

### Large number of new Threads

Do you really need to create and destroy that number of Threads? a better implementation might call the methods of [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to create its tasks, as it has automatic `Thread` management, the [`newCachedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()) has the performance characteris you require, automatic new threads when needed, but reusing old `Thread`s when they are free.

### Unbuffered IO

> ```
> public void connect(final String ip, final int port) throws IOException {
>     close();
>     socket = new Socket(ip, port);
>     input = socket.getInputStream();
>     output = socket.getOutputStream();
> }
> ```

You mainly use unbuffered io streams to the socket, this is really expansive as the calls propagate down the networking stack of the operating system. Wrapping the streams in `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream` makes the calls quicker as there are less half filled packets.

```
public void connect(final String ip, final int port) throws IOException {
    close();
    socket = new Socket(ip, port);
    input = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}
```

### To many flushes

> ```
>             if (io.isConnected()){
>                 while (queue.size() > 0) {
>                     final byte[] sendBytes = queue.remove();
>                     io.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sendBytes.length).array());
>                     io.write(sendBytes);
>                     io.flush();
>                 }
>             }
> ```

You flushing after every packet, by placing the final flush call after the loop, and wrapping everything into a if-statement that checks the size, you can send more packets in just one `flush()` call, this means only 1 tcp packet even if you send 5 small application specific packets

```
            if (io.isConnected()){
                if(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    do {
                        final byte[] sendBytes = queue.remove();
                        io.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sendBytes.length).array());
                        io.write(sendBytes);
                    } while (queue.size() > 0);
                    io.flush();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the write up! Gonna try and learn/ mess around with the Executors this weekend :)